# How to combine multiple rows into one row based on matching names in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

So I'm importing a database into Google Sheets, and it put all the entries in separate rows instead of a singular row like I need it to be to work with the rest of my data. I'm trying to figure out if there is a formula that can be used to create the dynamic I'm looking for below:

Import:

```
Name            | Group  | Purchase  | Quanity
Mike Smith      | A      | Apples    | 4
John Matthews   | B      | Oranges   | 10
John Matthews   | B      | Peaches   | 2
John Matthews   | B      | Oranges   | 8
Yanni Karlo     | A      | Limes     | 23
Yanni Karlo     | A      | Apples    | 15
```

Ideal Result:

```
Name           | Group | Purchase 1 | Quanity 1 | Purchase 2 | Quanity 2 | Purchase 3 | Quanity 3
Mike Smith     | A     | Apples     | 4         |            |           |            |
John Matthews  | B     | Oranges    | 10        | Peaches    | 2         | Oranges    | 8
Yanni Karlo    | A     | Limes      | 23        | Apples     | 15        |            |
```

Went looking online, found many ways to combine them into a cell and other things of the sort, but I guess I haven't been able to figure how to get a pivot to work while keeping the first two col in tact. Also looking for this to be native to sheets and not through an add-on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),lambda(Σ,{Σ,xlookup(Σ,A:A,B:B,),torow(filter(C:D,A:A=Σ))}))
```

[image]